# Options for a rear outlet toilet

Tags: shower, toilet, floor

I recently purchased a converted loft and would like to renovate the bathroom.

The layout of the bathroom is a simple rectangle with a sink, toilet and shower across one wall.  Most of the bathroom floor is at the same level as the rest of the unit; however, the shower is elevated ~3" to allow for underneath plumbing.  It then has a glass wall and curb to contain the water.  By contrast, the toilet is at ground level and has a rear outlet drain.

Both the ground floor and the elevated shower floor have leveling issues and I am looking to fix them.  As this fix is disruptive to the entire bathroom, I thought I would expand the scope and consider other potential improvements.  An obvious choice would be to make the entire bathroom floor a consistent height and move the curb to the entry.  This would allow the entire floor to use the shower drain, as well as adjusting how much space is devoted to the shower and toilet areas.  However, it was pointed out that this would require raising the rear drain for the toilet, and that could be expensive.  Because it is a unit within a larger building, I cannot push the drainage down.

My question is:

1. What are the potential costs and difficulties of raising the rear outlet for a toilet?
2. Are there other ideas/options for addressing the inconveniences of a bathroom floor with different levels?

Comment: Perhaps ask a plumber for a quote and see how they would do it.  Otherwise please post some photos and measurements of floor level difference.